# Defining Global variables with conditional compiling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables, preprocessor

I want to use global variables for defining the API base path of my app based on the current building configurations (dev, production). 
These are the current approaches:

1)

```
     struct ApiSettings {

     static  let API_DEV_BASEPATH = "http://dev.myapp.com"
     static  let API_PRODUCTION_BASEPATH = "http://prod.myapp.com"

    // Return the basepath for the current app runtime mode
    static var API_BASEPATH:String {

        var bPath: String!
        #if DEBUG
            bPath = API_DEV_BASEPATH
        #else
            bPath = API_PRODUCTION_BASEPATH
        #endif
        return bPath
    }
}
```

2)
 (Here I define a staging environment too)

```
#if DEBUG
let API_BASEPATH = "http://dev.app.com"
#elseif STAGING
let API_BASEPATH = "http://staging.app.com"
#elseif RELEASE
let API_BASEPATH = "http://production.app.com"
#endif
```

but when I try to use API_BASEPATH in my app the compiler complains about an "Unresolved Identifier"

I'm not sure which the most elegant solutions to be adopted. 
PS. I'm using Swift3

Comment: It would be a much better design to extract all environment-dependant variables into `plist` files.

Comment: is there any way of defining the same variable in a .plist file and extracting it based on the build configuration (debug, staging,release) without using code? I'm thinking of extending the code provided in the answer with constant extracted by the .plist

Comment: Yeah, you make one plist per build config, and change which one gets included with each package

Comment: ok thanks a lot. What do you think about the suggested answer?

Answer (score 2):

please try this.

```
static var API_BASEPATH:String {
        get {
            var bPath: String!
            #if DEBUG
                bPath = API_DEV_BASEPATH
            #else
                bPath = API_PRODUCTION_BASEPATH
            #endif
            return bPath
        }

    }
```

hope this will fix your confusion.